# LDAP restart causing connection refused error

Tags: java, ldap, redundancy

I am using ldapjdk 1.4.2_05_b04. 
I am doing load test with 2 LDAP configured.
When load test is running,i will make LDAP1 down and request is sent to LDAP2.
Please find the below scenario:

```
  **LDAP1**          **LDAP2**
 1)  UP                  UP
 2)  DOWN                UP
 3)  RESTART             UP
 4)  UP                  DOWN
 5)  UP                  RESTART
 6)  UP                  UP
```

Above scenario is done, and after 6th step, the request is not sent to any LDAP.

Any suggestion or help is appreciable and it is very critical issue.
Please help me in resolving the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is 'ldapjdk 1.4.2_05_b04'? Where does OpenLDAP come into it? How have you configured your client-side LDAP failover? Not enough information provided here.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the response.I am using netscape ldap and this is the version "ldapjdk 1.4.2_05_b04". No i have not configured at client side LDAP failover.

Comment: After 2 restart(after 6th step),tcp connections from application server to LDAP server is reducing.Before restart of any LDAP,tcp connection will be 151(apprx from both ldap) but after restart it will be reduced to 7(apprx).Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: What application? Can you show some code?   LDAP 1.4.2.x is very old.